# Delphi: Verify DataSnap connection via TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, connection, datasnap

We have an application in which the user can talk to us, it works fine, he create a new conversation, we chat, and that's ok. But, before start chatting, he needs to connect to the DataSnap Server, and that's where I'm trying to make a Thread. Every 5min, a timer would trigger his event to create the Thread and try to connect on the server, as below:

My Thread:

```
unit UThreadSnapConnection;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Data.SqlExpr;

type
  TThreadSnapConnection = class(TThread)
  private
    FSnap: TSQLConnection;
    procedure TryToConnect;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create;
  public
    DMSnap: TSQLConnection;
    HostName: String;
    Port: String;
  end;

implementation

{ TThreadSnapConnection }

constructor TThreadSnapConnection.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TThreadSnapConnection.TryToConnect;
begin
  try
    FSnap := DMSnap.CloneConnection;
    FSnap.Connected := False;

    try
      FSnap.Connected := True;
    except

    end;

    if FSnap.Connected then
      DMSnap.Connected := True;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FSnap);
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadSnapConnection.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(TryToConnect);
end;

end.
```

My Timer:

```
procedure TMyDataModuleSnap.TimerSnapTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyThread: TThreadSnapConnection;
begin
  if not(MySQLConnection.Connected) then
  begin
    MyThread := TThreadSnapConnection.Create;

    MyThread.DMSnap   := MySQLConnection;
    MyThread.HostName := 'localhost';
    MyThread.Port     := '211';

    MyThread.Resume;
  end;
end;
```

What I'm doing is an attempt to connect to the server, if it works, then it will make my data module connect.

My problem is, everytime the line

```
FSnap.Connected := True;
```

execute it freezes for 1~2 seconds the application, and the reason I made a thread was to not freeze. As long as I know, it should not bother at all the application, so I started to think maybe it's the work it does when setting the Connected property to True, which will freeze independent if it's thread or not.

**Is there any way to not freeze when trying to connect?**

And this is my first thread and maybe I just misunderstood things and that's not how thread works, but well, if it is not then I need to know, or at least understand what I'm doing wrong with it.

EDIT: The test I'm doing is, I start the application without starting the server, so it will try to connect unsuccessful, and my data module will not connect too.

Comment: You are calling `Synchronize(TryConnect)` in the thread. This means that you are connecting in the main thread.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, but I though that the `Synchronize` would make it parallel to the application, like, the two of them running at the same time without interfering in one another. Isn't it?

Comment: No, `Synchronize` means that the code will be executed in the main thread. See [TThread.Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. while the `OnTimer` event of a `TTimer` is executed in the thread which has created the timer, you may consider to create the instance outside the main thread
2. you may consider to use a `TThread` class instance

The following applies to the #2.

Using a `TEvent` in the `Execute` procedure of your thread you can wait for an amount of `FInterval` time before the execution of the next block of code.
When the `Terminated` property is set to `True`, this approach allows the `Execute` method to immediately return also during the interval count unlike the adoption of a `TThread.Sleep(FInterval);` call which would freeze the thread itself for the amount of time specified.

The main thread can be optionally notified using a `TNotifyEvent` when done.

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FInterval: Integer;
    FTerminateEvent: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    OnEndJob: TNotifyEvent;
    constructor Create(Interval: Cardinal; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(Interval: Cardinal; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FInterval := Interval;
  FTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  FTerminateEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  FTerminateEvent.SetEvent;
end

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    //do your stuff

    //notify your connection to the main thread if you want
    if Assigned(OnEndJob) then
      Synchronize(procedure
          begin
            OnEndJob(Self);
          end);

    //wait fo some amount of time before continue the execution
    if wrSignaled = FterminateEvent.WaitFor(FInterval) then
      Break;
  end;
end;
```

---

Don't *synchonize* the code you want to be executed in a thread: in Delphi a syncronized block is always executed in the calling thread.

Comment: What should be a "real" thread? I don't think I get what you're trying to say.

Comment: @GeovaneS a "real" `TThread` class which allows a better control on the `Execute` method: where your relevant code may be executed in the main thread in a `syncronized` manner or not

Comment: That's it. Like I expected mine to work like. But couldn't do. I just don't get what's happening there, like, what is the `FWaitEvent.WaitFor(FInterval);` for? And why it's necessary to have a `while not Terminated do` loop.

Comment: the `TEvent` works as a timer: it wait some amount of time before continue the execution

Comment: the loop that evaluate `Terminated` is necessary only if you want the code to be executed more than once. When `Terminated` evaluates to `True`, the `Execute` method returns

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred to post a comment rather than an answer, but lack the reputation points; something worth considering when reading the following.

Reading between the lines, it looks like you have a connection to a local SQL server. Access is infrequent causing the connection to drop, so you've instituted a timer to check every 5 mins and re-establish the connection if necessary.

This worked, but you found that the connection attempt blocks program execution until it is established, and so you want to move this operation to a worker thread.

As stated by fantaghirocco, Synchronize causes code to run within the main program thread. My understanding is this code runs after all messages in the main thread have been processed, so you could achieve the same result by having the timer post a message, and the associated message handler call TryToConnect (TryToConnect declared in the main form in this case).

Synchronize is the easiest means of allowing threads to interact with the main thread without having to worry about two or more threads accessing the same object at the same time.

To prevent the connection process from blocking the main program thread, the MySQLConnection Connected property would have to be set in the Execute method of the TThread descendant (not encapsulated within a call to Synchronize).

But doing so introduces the risk of the worker thread and main program accessing MySQLConnection at the same time. To protect against this you would need to introduce a critical section, or similar. If unfamiliar, then check TCriticalSection in the RAD Studio help; there's a section on Critical Sections and an example.

Both the main program and thread would then encapsulate any calls to MySQLConnection within a critical section try finally block:

```
FLock.Acquire;
try
  {code accessing MySQLConnection goes here}
finally
  FLock.Release;
end;
```

Where FLock is a TCriticalSection object.

Any thread attempting to acquire FLock while already acquired by another, will be blocked until FLock is released. This means the main thread would only be blocked if the user attempted access to MySQLConnection when the worker thread was already attempting a connection.

Update:

To get you started, the following is a simple program consisting of two units; Unit1 contains the main form (what you're presented with when you create a new application). The second unit, Unit2 contains a thread. I've done it this way since your thread appears to be in a separate unit.

I've added a button and a critical section to TForm1 (add System.SyncObjs to the uses clause). In the click event of Button1 I create an instance of TMyThread (in your code this would be handled by the timer event):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    FLock: TCriticalSection;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMyThread.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLock := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLock.Free;
end;
```

Unit2 contains the thread. The execute method is a fire once and finish effort. Unit1 is added to the uses clause in the implementation to give the code access to the Form1 variable:

```
type
  TMyThread = class (TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

uses Unit1;


{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create (False);
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  with Form1 do begin
    FLock.Acquire;
    try
      {access MySQLConnection methods here}
    finally
      FLock.Release;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When you run this simple program and click Button1, a separate thread is created and the execute method run, following which the thread is destroyed. This process is repeated every time you click Button1.

If you place a breakpoint in Unit1 on the `MyThread := TMyThread.Create` line, and another breakpoint in Unit2 on the `FLock.Acquire` line, run the program and click Button1, the code will stop in the main thread; the thread Id shown in the left hand pane. 
If you click F9 to continue program execution, it will then stop on the Unit2 breakpoint. You'll note the thread Id is now different, and the Thread Status window down the bottom of the IDE now lists this extra thread. When you press F9 again and this new thread disappears.

This program does nothing, but you would place whatever MySQLConnection code you needed to run in this thread where I have the comment in the Try Finally block.

In the main thread, wherever MySQLConnection's methods are accessed, you will also need to encapsulate these within a FLock try finally block. For example, if you have a TClientDataSet connected to a TDataSetProvider connected to a TSQLDataSet connected to your MySQLConnection, then opening the TClientDataSet will have to be encapsulated within this FLock Try Finally:

```
begin
  FLock.Acquire;
  try
    CDS.Open;
  finally
    FLock.Release;
  end;
end;
```

Where CDS is the TClientDataSet.

The code you intend to run in the thread basically closes the connection and re-opens it. A side benefit of the critical section (if properly configured, and all access to MySQLConnection protected by the critical section), is it will prevent the connection being shut in the middle of a user's query.

Comment: Thanks for a brief explaining of how `TCriticalSection` works, I see you have a good point when it comes to the two of them connecting at the same time. I'm guessing that i need to declare the `FLock` in the private section of my thread, couldn't it be just a local variable on the `Execute` procedure? If no, why?

Comment: @GeovaneSilveira if I'm allowed, `FLock` have to be used by every process which try to access the shared resource. One option is to declare it in your `private` section of the form. The shared method have to be in the form too. In order to allow the threads to gain access to the resorce without the need of an instance of the form, you may consider to use `class` variables and methods.

Comment: @GeovaneSilveira: As indicated by fantaghirocco, FLock has to be accessible to the relevant methods in both the main form and worker thread. The best place for FLock is the main form. If FLock is in the thread, it will not exist until the thread is created, and will cease to exist when the thread is destroyed. That will make things difficult for methods in the main form that need to use the critical section. If the thread is defined in the same unit as the main form, then it will be able to access private variables declared in the form.

Comment: @CAnder  *the lock (acquire/release) have to be in the called method only* and not in the `Execute` method of the thread. If the `FLock` is private to the form you'll have to care about lock/release only in one place or any thread accessing the method will have to know about the lock

Comment: @CAnder what I mean is: 1) the lock is `private` to the form; 2) the form has a `public` method to verify the connection 3) the method code is in between a critical section 4) the thread calls the form's public method. Your current approach does not require that the form knows about `FLock` but it can be a statically initialized `class` variable of the thread

Comment: @fantaghirocco: Yes, I agree with your reasoning. The example is intended to provide as simple a solution as possible to aid familiarization.

Comment: @CAnder I agree with *aid familiarization* but it seems to me that the solution introduces some odds which the OP may wrongly consider the right approach to `TCriticalSection`. Anyway I think that your overview is fine :)